# SQL: how to remove duplicate rows when value in Column 1 = value in Column 2 and vice versa

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a table like this:

| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 41d97f0c-7c0b-441b-b947-d18ad2778899 | 1feb623f-781f-4c0e-9230-861970bd2e91 | random1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1feb623f-781f-4c0e-9230-861970bd2e91 | 41d97f0c-7c0b-441b-b947-d18ad2778899 | random2 | 2022-01-01 |
| 7c1cbb7b-fefc-4ab8-827d-4e1a9a130da9 | 4722b35b-7ebb-4bb7-bd84-bd290fba5d3e | random3 | 2022-01-02 |
| 1313a680-5f87-4c03-b8a0-4c5743f0f2a4 | da67bcae-dad5-4122-95a2-7f6c32ca85e7 | random4 | 2022-01-03 |
| da67bcae-dad5-4122-95a2-7f6c32ca85e7 | 1313a680-5f87-4c03-b8a0-4c5743f0f2a4 | random5 | 2022-01-04 |

For all rows where column_1 == column_2 and column_2 == column_1, I want to remove one of them as its a duplicate. In above example first 2 rows are duplicates, so I want to ignore 2nd row. Last 2 rows are also duplicates so I want to remove last row. The end result should look like:

| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 41d97f0c-7c0b-441b-b947-d18ad2778899 | 1feb623f-781f-4c0e-9230-861970bd2e91 | random1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 7c1cbb7b-fefc-4ab8-827d-4e1a9a130da9 | 4722b35b-7ebb-4bb7-bd84-bd290fba5d3e | random3 | 2022-01-02 |
| 1313a680-5f87-4c03-b8a0-4c5743f0f2a4 | da67bcae-dad5-4122-95a2-7f6c32ca85e7 | random4 | 2022-01-03 |

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using? (Remove the non-related tags.)

Comment: I removed all inconsistent database tags. Please tag a single database only.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you! Sample data like A, B and C are much easier to handle than 41d97f0c-7c0b-441b-b947-d18ad2778899, 41d93f0c-7c0b-441b-b947-d18ad2778899 and 41d97f0c-7c0b-441b-b947-d18ad2778g99.

Comment: BigQuery. Next time will use sample data. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
select *
from t a
left join t b on b.col1 = a.col2 and b.col2 = a.col1
where b.col1 is null or a.col1 < b.col1
```

Comment: Believe answer is correct, just one minor issue. In your ON clause, there's a space instead of a period for "a col2"

Comment: @Stephan Thanks for spotting the error.

Comment: @Stephan  in similar query if I try to use "Not Equal To" as  `a.col1 <> b.col1` instead of  "Less Than" as `a.col1 < b.col1` then I get different result. I read documentation but not able to find out why it is happening. could you please explain this to me... I have also  tried below queries `SELECT 'ABC' = 'ABC'; -- 1 (true);`
 `SELECT 'ABC' <> 'ABC'; -- 0 (false);`
  `SELECT 'ABC' < 'ABC'; -- 0 (false);`

Comment: @PrakashMhasavekar not sure I understand your issue, sounds like you might need to create your own Stackoverflow question.

A "Less than (<)" comparison is not equivalent to a "not equal to (<>)" check. In case of numbers 2 < 1 is false, but 2<> 1 is true, in your case of text it would be sort order.
'A' < 'B' is true, 'A' <> 'B' is true, but 'B" < 'A' is false

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just want to keep one row for all distinct values across column_1 and column_2. The below should work.

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table 
WHERE 
  column_1 NOT IN (SELECT column_2 FROM table)
UNION
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table 
WHERE 
  column_2 NOT IN (SELECT column_1 FROM table)
```